# 3 different codes to do the same thing, only, one of them works (need the 3 working)

Tags: python, arrays

I'm a student who missed a year of classes and is now having to catch up with a lot of things because if have year 1 and 2 classes mixed.

Two days ago I had little to no programming knowledge aside from knowing to print or make a sum.

I'm faced with a problem which is calculating the maximum difference of the numbers in a list.

ex : [10 , 555 , 40 ] - Maximum difference is = 545

my input has to be the number of elements of the list and then the elements themselves.

for example:

input:

```
3

10 555 40
```

output:

```
545
```

I need to have 3 approaches in order to do this. The first one is an extensive one where I need to have two cycles to verify the absolute difference of every combination of two numbers.

The second one I have to sort the list and and calculate the absolute difference between the first and last element.

The third one I need to have two variables, listmax and listmin (biggest and smallest value) and I need to go through the list with a cycle and update the values.

my solution of the **SECOND ONE** is the only one that works 100%, as its the easiest.

(I'm submitting the code to a site that checks the output and only the second solution is accepted, the other two fail)

my solution one code:

```
   from sys import stdin,stdout
def readln():
 return stdin.readline().rstrip()
def outln(n):
 stdout.write(str(n))
 stdout.write("\n")
n = int(input(""))
arr = [int(i) for i in readln().split()]
tam = len(arr)
max_diff = 0
if len(arr) != n:
 print("the number of elements in the list is not correct")
else:
  for i in range(tam):
   for j in range(i,tam):
    if (abs(arr[i] - arr[j] > max_diff)):
     max_diff = abs(arr[j] - arr[i])
  outln(max_diff)
```

this one doesn't work because if my list is 40, 555, 10 it returns 515 which is incorrect.

my solution 3 code:

```
    from sys import stdin, stdout
def readln():
 return stdin.readline().rstrip()
def outln(n):
 stdout.write(str(n))
 stdout.write("\n")
n = int(input(""))
arr = ([int(i) for i in readln().split()])
if len(arr) != n:
 print("the number of elements in the list is not correct")
else:
 min = arr[0]
 max = arr[0]
 for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] < min: min = arr[i]
 if arr[i] > max: max = arr[i]
outln(max-min)
```

this one returns 30 when the list is 10, 555, 40.

Only my second one works, which I feel I don't need to show here since its the most basic.

Help a noob out, any help is appreciated! (note that I copied some of the code, and other parts of it were made by myself, there are some things there that I don't understand although I do understand most of it).

Comment: Welcome to SO! As your 2 non-working programs fail for different reasons, I suggest you should make 2 questions each focusing on one of them. No need to tell us about the one that works fine. Also please check your indentation.

Comment: Code 1 solution has parentheses in wrong place.  The if statement should be: `if abs(arr[i] - arr[j]) > max_diff:`

Comment: In solution 3 the problem may be the wrong indentation of `if arr[i] > max: max = arr[i]`

Comment: @Stuart that was actually it. thanks a lot. ill be sure to organize the question better next time i post here.

Answer (score 0):

Correction to Code 1 for loop section

```
max_diff = 0
for i in range(tam):
    for j in range(i,tam):
        if abs(arr[i] - arr[j]) > max_diff: # this line incorrect in posted code
            max_diff = abs(arr[j] - arr[i])

outln(max_diff)
```

Correction to Code 3 for loop section

```
min_ = max_ = arr[0]        # should not use max, min as variable names
                            # since same as built-in functions.  Can use min_, max_
for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    if arr[i] < min_: min_ = arr[i]
    if arr[i] > max_: max_ = arr[i]
        
outln(max_ - min_)
```